# Override order_date but query.php not working

Tags: templates, overrides, category-blog, joomla-3.6, sorting

I am looking for a solution to sort a Category-Blog by 'unpublish-date'.

What i have done so far:

1. created an own menu-style by copying
   `blog.xml`, `blog.php`, `blog-item.php` and `blog-links.php` to `my-*.*` into my template directory
2. checked menu-items: now i can select a category-blog (my~)
3. added the following line to `my-blog.xml`

   ```
   <option value="publish_down">JUNPUBLISHED</option>
   ```
4. selected 'unpubish' as order_date in menu-item

Hewe comes my problem now:

Some time ago i used to edit `query.php` in `root/components/com_content/helpers/` (i know its a core hack, now i want to do better) to add the 'publish_down' case like

```
case 'publish_down' :
    $queryDate = ' CASE WHEN a.publish_down = ' . $db->quote($db->getNullDate()) . ' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_down END ';
    break;
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work anymore.

Have you guys any hints for me? Appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid core hacks loading your own model to replace the original one. Please, check these links:

**How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core**
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

**Did you know? Overrides are not just for HTML!**
https://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/521-did-you-know-overrides-are-not-just-for-html.html

Comment: Hi Anibal,
unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It seems as if my core hack (editing the query.php) is overwritten by another compontent. Maybe another mvp-override.
After studying your hints i can not adapt them to my problem. (Just want to sorty by publish_down.)
Do you have any other hints that may help me?

Comment: Hi, a system plugin override is the best way to modify a core behavior. It  works 99% of the cases.

Comment: If it does not work. You have to check if the core class is already loaded before your plugin, and look for a way to load your version first.